# Performa a batch of operations with a user interaction in the middle of each

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, fifo

I need to perform some operations sequentially.
There are many objects that conforms to a protocol (with a method i.e. execute()) inserted in an array in order of execution.

All looks simple using GCD with something like:

```
dispatch_queue_t serialQuele = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);

for (id <ExecutableProtocol> exec in executables)
{
    dispatch_async(serialQuele, ^{
        [exec executeWithCompletionBlock:^(NSString *name, Status *state) {
            [self.executeResults setObject:state forKey:name];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (self.delegate)
                    [self.delegate didExecuted: exec withResult:state userInfo:userInfo];
            });
        }];
    });
}
```

The Idea looks good but if a executor asks the user one question with a UIAlertController... the next executor cannot show its dialog also with UIAlertController because user has not yet answered the question and the previous dialog is still showing.

How can I achieve what I would expect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think switching the order between the first `dispatch_async` and the loop and changing the `dispatch_async` to `dispatch_sync` achieves what you want. I am not certain that I have understood what it is that you want your code to do, so I might be wrong.

```
dispatch_async(serialQuele, ^{
   for (id <ExecutableProtocol> exec in executables)
   {
       [exec executeWithCompletionBlock:^(NSString *name, Status *state) {
          [self.executeResults setObject:state forKey:name];

          if (self.delegate) {
             dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self.delegate didExecuted: exec withResult:state userInfo:userInfo];
              )};
         }];
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lev but like you suggested the UI is freezing...on the log I saw all elements are executed but the ui is stopped on the first element and the user cannot answer because all is freezes.

Comment: That is strange. I struggle to see any reason why that would be. It would block of there is a `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...})` calls in the `didExecuted: withResult: userInfo` method, but I suppose you have checked that.

Comment: inside didExecuted method delegate there is ony a reloadData of a collectionView...